# Error that failed to call super.dispose in Flutter - despite calling super.dipose()?

Tags: flutter

I am getting an error that super.dispose failed to call, even though I am calling super.dipose in the overridden method and unsure why this error is occuring.

I've tried different approaches such as wrap super.dispose in  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { }) but that didnt work.

Any ideas why this might occur and is there a way I can force this /  fix it?

(Below I am selecting random words from a sqlite database, which all runs fine).

Thank you!

code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/Pages/WordMatch/answerManager.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/Pages/WordMatch/pageProgressBar.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/Pages/WordMatch/pageProgressManager.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/animations/colorChange.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/animations/customScrollPhysics.dart';
import 'package:learn_to_read/database/databaseManager.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'contents.dart';
import 'homeBar.dart';

class WordMatch extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _WordMatchState createState() => _WordMatchState();
}

class _WordMatchState extends State<WordMatch> with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _originalList = [];
  List<String> _selectedList = [];

  void newPage(int i) {
    context.read<AnswerManager>().currentPage = i;
    context.read<PageProgressManager>().incrementProgressDots(i);
  }

  Future<List<String>> generateData() async {
    DatabaseManager _databaseManager = DatabaseManager();
    Database _database = await _databaseManager.initDatabase();
    List<Map> _list = await _databaseManager.createList(_database);
    return List.generate(_list.length, (index) => _list[index]["Word"]);
  }

  Future<bool> populateLocalLists(List<String> _list) async {
    _originalList = _list;
    context.read<AnswerManager>().setTotalCards(_originalList.length);
    context.read<AnswerManager>().calculateTotalPages();

    return true;
  }

  Future<void> selectInitialWords(bool _listsPopulated) async {
    randomWordSelector();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void selectSubsequentWords(int i) async {
    _selectedList.clear();
    randomWordSelector();
  }

  void setUp() async {
    final _list = await generateData();
    final _listsPopulated = await populateLocalLists(_list);
    await selectInitialWords(_listsPopulated);
  }

  void initState() {
    context.read<PageProgressManager>().progressDotTracker = 0;
    context.read<AnswerManager>().resetVariables();
    bool accepted = false;

    setUp();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {

    if (context.read<AnswerManager>().currentPage !=
            Provider.of<AnswerManager>(context).itemCount &&
        Provider.of<AnswerManager>(context).cardsUpdated == false) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        selectSubsequentWords(0);
        context.read<AnswerManager>().resetPoints();
      });
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text('Match'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          HomeBar(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: context.watch<AnswerManager>().itemCount,
                pageSnapping: true,
                physics: CustomScrollPhysics(parent: null),
                onPageChanged: newPage,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (context, int) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    child: ColorChangeUser(
                      duration: 500,
                      colorBegin: Colors.orange,
                      colorEnd: Colors.green,
                      widget: Container(
                        child: Contents(
                          words: _selectedList,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          PageProgressBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void randomWordSelector() {
    if(_originalList.length == 0){return;}
    Random rn = Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      int j = rn.nextInt(_originalList.length);
      _selectedList.add(_originalList[j]);
      _originalList.removeAt(j);
    }
  }



}
```

error message

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
_WordMatchState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.

## dispose() implementations must always call their superclass dispose() method, to ensure that all the resources used by the widget are fully released.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      StatefulElement.unmount. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4804:7)
#1      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4811:6)
#2      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1847:13)
#3      _InactiveElements._unmount. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1845:7)
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6070:14)
...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK - so I finally figured what I was doing wrong in case anyone else makes the same mistake.

I had left ChangeNotifier (from Provider) on _WordMatchState (which I no longer wanted) and forgot to remove. Yay.